# add telephone number to ics organizer

Tags: icalendar

I was hoping to add a telephone number to my ICS file/invitation so when the attendee looks at the contact information both email and telephone are shown. This is my current line:

```
ORGANIZER;CN="{ORGANIZER_NAME}":mailto:{ORGANIZER_EMAIL}
```

Simply adding ;+0000000000 does not do the trick, that adds the phone number to the email address instead of mentioning it as a separate contact option.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification RFC5545,

1. the Organiser must be of type CAL-ADDRESS. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.3
2. CAL-ADDRESS must be a mail-to. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.3
3. The CONTACT for an event is of type TEXT and the examples given include telephone numbers https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.2
   eg:

   CONTACT:Jim Dolittle, ABC Industries, +1-919-555-1234

Comment: Added the line to my ICS file, but my iPhone doesn't show anything different from what it was.

Comment: Had a quick play myself, and yes it seems like the major calendar apps seem to expect that the email address will identify a contact that one already has in one's address book.    If the organiser is unknown to the attendees and the ics is being sent by email, perhaps including a VCARD in the invitation would help?

Comment: Do you think I can include it in the ics file I already have? It’s worth a try I guess.

Comment: This works as expected on my iPhone, so I’ll give it a try adding it to my ics: https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/5543.html

Comment: Do you mean using ATTACH? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.1   this would again be dependent on how the receiving applications treat it.

Comment: I don't seem to understand how "attach" will work. I have tried adding a vcard to the invitation, it does show the vcard and its information in the mail, but the vcalendar is still the same, so no telephone number included.